# How to calculate percentage over multiple rows over group by

Tags: mysql, sum, multiple-columns, percentage

For the solution rate of some of our tickets I want to calculate the percentage of solved tickets in relation to the total number of tickets of the same type in the same month
I am able to get the number of solved tickets, but I am missing the total of all the tickets from the same type and the same month so always 0% or 100%.
Question= How can i cumulate the count of tickets so I can calculate percentage of solved tickets per month, type, status?

I've a group by on time, type AND status (see query below). So the total is always overruled by the group by of the status.
I've tried: cumulatives, roll up, pivot, union

```
    SELECT date_format(st.createdDate,'%Y%m') createdAt,
       count(st.id) COUNT,
                    st.typeId,
                    st.status,
                    sum(st.status2) status2,
                    sum(st.notStatus2) notStatus2,
                    ((sum(st.status2)/sum(st.status2)+sum(st.notStatus2))*100) AS pct
FROM
  (SELECT t.id,
          t.added createdDate,
          t.type_id typeId,
          tt.name ticketType,
          t.status,
          if(t.status=2,1,0) AS status2,
          if(t.status!=2,1,0) AS notStatus2,
          datediff(closed,added) doorloopTijdDgn
   FROM tickets t
   JOIN ticket_types tt ON tt.id=t.type_id
   WHERE added BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2019-07-01' ) AS st #singletickets
GROUP BY createdAt,
         ticketType,
         status;
```

For the first two rows (type=62) I expect 33 out of 37 solved tickets = 89,2%
So "sum(st.status2)+sum(st.notStatus2)" of pct should be 37

Now I get:

```
createdAt  count  typeId  status  status2 notStatus2  pct
   201807     33      62       2       33          0  100.0000
   201807      4      62       6        0          4  NULL
   201807     31      38       2       31          0  100.0000
   201807      3      38       6        0          3  NULL
   201807     15      12       2       15          0  100.0000
   201807     11      11       2       11          0  100.0000
   201807      1      48       2        1          0  100.0000
   201807     19      30       2       19          0  100.0000
   201807      5       9       2       5           0  100.0000
   201807     12      33       2       12          0  100.0000
   201807      1      52       2        1          0  100.0000
   201807      2      45       2        2          0  100.0000
   201807     41      58       2       41          0  100.0000
   201807      3      58       6        0          3  NULL
   201807      1      41       6        0          1  NULL
   201807      1      13       2        1          0  100.0000
   201807     35      66       2       35          0  100.0000
   201807      8      20       2        8          0  100.0000
   201807      1      20       4        0          1  NULL
   201807      5      10       2        5          0  100.0000
   201807     12      68       2       12          0  100.0000
   201807      1      65       2        1          0  100.0000
   201807     20       7       2       20          0  100.0000
   201807      2      19       2        2          0  100.0000
   201807      4      43       2        4          0  100.0000
   201807      3      34       2        3          0  100.0000
   201807     24      67       2       24          0  100.0000
   201807     43      46       2       43          0  100.0000
   201807      1      46       6        0          1  NULL
```

What I want:

```
createdAt  count  typeId  status  status2 notStatus2  pct
   201807     33      62       2       33          0  89.2000
   201807      4      62       6        0          4  0
   201807     31      38       2       31          0  93.9000
   201807      3      38       6        0          3  0
   201807     15      12       2       15          0  100.0000
   201807     11      11       2       11          0  100.0000
   201807      1      48       2        1          0  100.0000
   201807     19      30       2       19          0  100.0000
   201807      5       9       2       5           0  100.0000
   201807     12      33       2       12          0  100.0000
   201807      1      52       2        1          0  100.0000
   201807      2      45       2        2          0  100.0000
   201807     41      58       2       41          0  93.2000
   201807      3      58       6        0          3  0
   201807      1      41       6        0          1  0
   201807      1      13       2        1          0  100.0000
   201807     35      66       2       35          0  100.0000
   201807      8      20       2        8          0  88.8000
   201807      1      20       4        0          1  0
```

**I have mysql 5.7.12 to work with**

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense. What column indicates if the ticket is solved or not?

Comment: status=2 = solved all other statuses not

Comment: added example of what i want from my query
MCRE is what I provided imho, even less would not show the problem I have

Comment: You haven't provided an MCRE. There's no 'R' here

Comment: OK I see, have to show dummy dataset and dummy query to ' reproduce'  problem.
Come back on it later this week as I have some other problem at hands. Thanks for the advice

Comment: still on it, however not yet able to create dummy data and query

Answer (score 0):

seems you have wrong ()

should be

```
((sum(st.status2)/(sum(st.status2)+sum(st.notStatus2)))*100) as pct
```

Comment: changes the null into '0', but doesn't solve my totals and percentage question